# Regex logical AND?

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regex that matches:.

```
[\d]{6,}
```

( = 6 consecutive digits)
but that does NOT match:

```
0[\d]{9}
```

(10 consecutive digits starting with 0)

I can obviously do it easily with 2 C# conditions.
if( Regex1.Match(pattern) && ! Regex2.Match(pattern) )
But in a particular case of my code, I would need to evaluate both with a single check.

I would like to know if there is a way to check the 2 conditions with a single Regex?

concrete exemple of what I need:

```
blabla

12345678 should be found

0123456789 should not be found

0123456 should be found

40666666666 should be found

bla
```

Thx in advance.

EDIT : edited the expected matches

Comment: Please provide a real life test case. It is not clear what context these digit chunks appear in. Actually, I think you might try the well-known technique to match what you do not need and capture what you need: `0\d{9}|(\d{6,})`. What is your end goal?

Comment: Do you mean both _6 digits_ OR _10 digits (starting with zero)_ in one unique regex?

Comment: in this example, I want to grab any sequence of at least 6 digits but exclude sequences of 10 consecutive digits starting with 0.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: OP mentions C#.

Comment: @A.D.: If you check the numbers as individual strings, you may also use `^(?!0\d{9}$)\d{6,}$`

Comment: hmm
^(?!0\d{9}$)\d{6,}$ 
does not seem to find >6 digits sequences as needed.

Comment: Maybe: `0*\K\d{6}`

Comment: Ok, you need to *find sequences*, so use `var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"0\d{9}|(\d{6,})").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList()`. In case you want to only exclude 10-digit chunks, add word boundaries: `@"\b0\d{9}\b|(\d{6,})"`

Comment: @Washington Guedes nope! :)
Check my post edit's bottom line to figure out what I want to match with a more concrete exemple. I should have provided that sooner.

Comment: There is no way to skip matches in .NET regex, use my approach. Match but only collect what is captured. Well, you could try nested lookarounds, but that would look too ugly and I am not sure they will work in this case at all.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew that probably works.
But I am using a nested regex engine that parses single regex strings and applies a IsMatch method.
So I won't be able to use your solution in this specific case.

If no single regex string can match my needs, I ll rather update the regex engine to accept as a parameter a List<Regex> instead of a Regex. But I wanted to checkout if a single regex can do the trick without I need to change my C#.

Comment: Then show the code you are using. If you could switch to PCRE.NET, you could use [`\b0\d{9}\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\d{6,}`](https://regex101.com/r/5cVYkS/1). But still, I think you should be able to use the native C# regex code with the approach I shared.

Comment: @ Washington Guedes :

(?m)^[1-9]\d{5,}

woohoo!! You got it man!! :)

Mark it as an answer?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew :
\b0\d{9}\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\d{6,}
does work too thx! :)
I had never seen those SKP FAILS patterns thx a lot for sharing.

Comment: As per the current requirements, `(?m)^[1-9]\d{5,}` cannot work (it won't match `0123456`, while it should be since it is not a 10-digit number starting with `0`), but suit yourself.

Comment: I also think `(?m)^` is just wrong

Comment: Hm, C# throws on
new Regex(@"\b0\d{9}\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\d{6,}");
" {x,y} quantifier following nothing" Exception
Is there anything special to do?

Comment: Should it match `012345678` and `01234567890`?

Comment: @ Washington Guedes : yep

Comment: I'm not sure anymore, let me read it again :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write your regex a way, that all conditions are in one regex.

You could for example use [boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (\b) to say, that your string has something else (letter, sign or space) following your numbers and something else preceding your numbers, and the feature of [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (Pipe) to give some special instructions for "starting with 0":

```
\b(0\d{5,8}|0\d{10,}|[1-9]\d{5,})\b
```

example: https://regex101.com/r/YIJh9g/4

But, as someone pointed out: please bring a real world example.

Comment: Hi Swe,
I think you missed the main point to exclude the 10digits matches starting with 0 from the matches that you found.

Comment: i updated, same idea as @WashingtonGuedes, please review my answer

Comment: @ Washington Guedes 
\b(0\d{5,8}|0\d{10,}|\d{6,}) is nearly good.
But it matches 012345678 in 0123456789.
Trying to exclude that

Comment: please review my answer

Comment: Hmm
looks you got it guys with:
\b(0\d{5,8}|0\d{10,}|[1-9]\d{5,})\b
Looks it s good this time.

Comment: I managed to make it simpler with a zero-with negative lookahead. `\b((?!0\d{9}\b)\d{6,})\b`.